# Can't create basic stored proc on MariaDB

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

The documented stored procedure on the MariaDB page fails to execute for me:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/create-procedure/

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
 BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
 END;
//
```

I get this error:

The following errors were reported:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT) BEGIN SELECT COUNT' at line 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 1

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your SQL works for me when run from the command line (e.g. "mysql -uroot dbname < somefile.sql"). How are you running it?

Comment: Turned out to be a custom setup of the db so contacted the admin. Still not working, but getting there.

Comment: me too have an error while creating procedure, but the procedure is created and work smoothly. MariaDB bugs?

Comment: I'm doing the same thing using phpMyAdmin. If I use a single character delimiter like `$`, there reportedly is a syntax error after the "begin", but the procedure gets created and works. If I use the `//` as delimiter, the error is an punctuation problem regarding the `//` and the procedure does not get created.

Comment: Correction: MariaDB says, there was a syntax error near "procedure", because "or replace" does not seem to exist in MariaDB. The errors stay the same though, but the procedure works in both cases now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adds the following statement to the end of the script: `DELIMITER ;`

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT) BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```